# Pandas remove all of a string in a column after a character

Tags: python, pandas, object, replace

So I have a data set with over 500 rows where one of the columns has values like this:

df:

```
         column1

 0    a{'...'}  
 1    b{'...'}
 2    c{'...'}  
 3    d{'...'}
```

I want to remove everything within and including the `{}`.

I have been looking at this question, [Pandas delete parts of string after specified character inside a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767376/pandas-delete-parts-of-string-after-specified-character-inside-a-dataframe) and tried the solutions there but I keep getting errors(And I am aware that `StringIO` is now `io.StringIO`).

I've tried

```
df.column1 = df.column1.str.split('{')[0]
```

but get the error message: `KeyError: 0`  and don't really understand what that means

I've also tried:

```
df.column1 = df.column1.str.split(pat='{')
```

But this only seems deletes the '{' so I'm left with

```
      column1

 0    a'...'}   
 1    b'...'}
 2    c'...'}   
 3    d'...'}
```

Also I'm not sure if it's important but the column is an `object` type.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix the issue???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can using `replace`

```
df['column1'].str.replace(r"\{.*\}","")
Out[385]: 
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
Name: column1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 5):

A little late (@Wen's solution is great), but you *can* use [`pandas.Series.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) as in your original attempt. You were close- you just need to set `expand=True`.

```
df["column1"] = df["column1"].str.split("{", expand=True)[0]
#  column1
#0       a
#1       b
#2       c
#3       d
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `pandas.DataFrame.replace` and pass a dictionary that specifies what to do for various columns.

Using @Wen's regex pattern

```
df.replace(dict(column1={'\{.*\}': ''}), regex=True)

  column1
0       a
1       b
2       c
3       d
```

---

In the spirit of @pault, you can also use `pandas.Series.str.extract`

```
df.column1.str.extract('([^\{]+)', expand=False)

  column1
0       a
1       b
2       c
3       d
```

Comment: @Aongoose you can upvote many answers (when you have 15+ rep) but you can only accept one answer.  By accepting my answer, you un-accepted Wen's answer.  That may not have been your intention.  If not, feel free to accept Wen's answer again by clicking on the checkmark.

Comment: yup that's my bad thanks for the heads up @piRSquared

Answer (score 0):

Using `.apply`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["a{'...'}", "b{'...'}"]})
df["a"] = df["a"].apply(lambda x: x.split('{')[0])
print df
```