# Split function not working

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling to determine as to why my split function along with code is not working. I have a column like this -

**RegionName**
   Alabama[edit]
   Auburn (Auburn University)
   Florence(University of North Alabama)
   Jacksonville
   .
   .
   .
and so on..

The above entries show the cases that are there in the column. What i want to achieve is for entries having state names such as Alabama[edit], i want to have it displayed as NaN, for remaining other entries which are corresponding regions within that particular State, i want to clean all those entries if required. If no cleaning required, i want that entry to stay intact.i am using below code-

```
for x in Town['RegionName']:
    if re.match(r"\s*\(",x):
        x.split('(').strip()
    elif re.match(r"\d+\[",x):
        x = np.NaN
    else:
        x
```

The code runs without any error but all the entries stay intact. The desired output is -

**RegionName**
   NaN
   Auburn
   Florence
   Jacksonville
   .
   .
   .
Cleaning required is - remove the entire content post parenthesis, there could be a space between required content and parenthesis so have to take that as well into account.

Please advise.

Comment: The `x` in the statement `for x in Town['RegionName']` is only in the scope of the `for` loop; you are just changing a copy not the actual element.

Comment: Where is this file from? I can't believe how many times this question has been asked!

Comment: I tried searching for this as i also believed that someone might have asked this question before but couldn't come across one so i had to ask myself here. I regret for any inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating over rows in `pandas` is discouraged when avoidable because it's slow. Here's a faster, vectorized approach to your problem, using `np.where`:

```
Towns["RegionName"] = np.where(
    Towns["RegionName"].str.contains("\[edit\]"),
    np.nan,
    Towns["RegionName"].str.split("(\s)?\(", expand=True)[0]
)
print(Towns["RegionName"])
#0             NaN
#1          Auburn
#2        Florence
#3    Jacksonville
#Name: RegionName, dtype: object
```

The first argument to `np.where` is a condition. If the condition is `True`, the second argument is returned. If it is `False`, the last argument is returned. For replacing everything including and after the `(`, I used the answer I posted on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820285/pandas-remove-all-of-a-string-in-a-column-after-a-character/49820808#49820808).

Comment: Hi.  I have one doubt. in .where clause, [0] has been appended at the end of the statement. I verified that in its absence, the shape of the column changes to (567,7) and it throws the error, whereas, the right shape is (567,) which is obtained by the code provided. I want to understand how this change is happening through that [0], if you can please explain some concept behind that. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: `split(..., expand=True)` will return a multiple columns. `[0]` gets the first one, which is everything before the pattern on which we split. Look at the output of `Towns["RegionName"].str.split("(\s)?\(", expand=True)` by itself an d this will be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the value back to the list items

```
for i, x in enumerate(Town['RegionName']):
    # Manipulation of x
    ...
    Town['RegionName'][i] = x
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.apply`  with `lambda` and `str.split`

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["Alabama[edit]", "Auburn (Auburn University)", "Jacksonville"]})
print(df["a"].apply(lambda x: np.nan if "[edit]" in x else x.split("(")[0].strip()))
```

**Output:**

```
0             NaN
1          Auburn
2    Jacksonville
Name: a, dtype: object
```